# implement stripe in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to implement stripe in my react.js app but I have a problem with stripe docs they used a component made to collect the card data `cardElement` and I don't want to use this.
I want to send the data from my inputs but I don't find anywhere what keys should I send.

Answer (score 1):

You're strongly recommend **not** to do that for compliance purposes.

https://stripe.com/en-sg/guides/pci-compliance